# LibreOffice upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, libreoffice, repository

I am currently running Ubuntu 18.04. Libreoffice gets periodically upgraded but is at version 6.0.7.3. I understand that there is a stable version 6.2.n available from the web-site. I would like to know why is LibreOffice not getting upgraded to 6.2.n. Do I have to purge the existing version and reinstall to get latest LibreOffice version? Do I need to change the repository every time there is a major stable release of LibreOffice?

Comment: Ubuntu releases with software that was available (provided it's released with enough time to package, test & include) at the time of release; and security-fixes are back-ported to that software UNLESS the back-porting of security fixes requires more time (package/testing) that switching to a newer version. If you want later packages, you're best moving to the next release (ie. 18.10, 19.04, 19.10).  By going the PPA/3rd party route, you take security responsibility on yourself, and may need to remove that software for next *release-upgrade* (ie. that will be more difficult).  Your choice.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libreoffice  shows the LibreOffice versions available on each release.  I'm running LibreOffice 6.3.3.2 30(Build:2) currently on 20.04   *ie. I think it's safer to stick to the default Ubuntu packaged versions, upgrading releases if you need later software.  FYI: I'm on 20.04 for testing purposes; ie. current development release*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu releases with software that was available (*provided it's released with enough time to package, test & include*) at the time of release; and security-fixes are back-ported to that software UNLESS the back-porting of security fixes requires more time (package/testing) that switching to a newer version.

*Back-ported upgrades do not include new features, only the security fixes from later versions of software.*

If you want later packages, you're best moving to the next release every six months (ie. 18.10, 19.04, 19.10 & soon 20.04).

By going the PPA/3rd party route, you take security responsibility on yourself (*is the PPA safe, secure, maintained, ensuring that into the future yourself*), and may need to remove that software for next *release-upgrade* (ie. making your next release bump more difficult).

It's your choice

> ```
> xenial (16.04LTS) (editors): office productivity suite (metapackage) [universe]
> 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial10 [security]: amd64 i386
> 1:5.1.2-0ubuntu1 [ports]: arm64 armhf powerpc ppc64el s390x
> xenial-updates (editors): office productivity suite (metapackage) [universe]
> 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial10: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el s390x
> bionic (18.04LTS) (editors): office productivity suite (metapackage) [universe]
> 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 [security]: amd64 i386
> 1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1 [ports]: arm64 armhf ppc64el s390x
> bionic-updates (editors): office productivity suite (metapackage) [universe]
> 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
> cosmic (18.10) (editors): office productivity suite (metapackage) [universe]
> 1:6.1.2-0ubuntu1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
> cosmic-updates (editors): office productivity suite (metapackage) [universe]
> 1:6.1.6-0ubuntu0.18.10.3: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
> disco (19.04) (editors): office productivity suite (metapackage) [universe]
> 1:6.2.7-0ubuntu0.19.04.1 [security]: amd64 i386
> 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu2 [ports]: arm64 armhf ppc64el s390x
> disco-updates (editors): office productivity suite (metapackage) [universe]
> 1:6.2.8-0ubuntu0.19.04.1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
> eoan (editors): office productivity suite (metapackage) [universe]
> 1:6.3.2-0ubuntu2: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
> ```

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libreoffice

shows the LibreOffice versions available on each release.

I think it's safer to stick to the default Ubuntu packaged versions, upgrading releases (off LTS cycle) if you need the latest software.